# Array of an Object error accessing variables: NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, .net, class, windows-phone-7, object

Ok so I'm attempting to create a high score system and am using an array of a class within an object, however the error in the title appears which tells me that for some reason my objects are full of null variables, here are my classes:

```
class HighScores
{
    public HighScore[] MyScores = new HighScore[5];

    protected bool failedRead = false;

    private void SortHighScores(string NewName, int NewScore)
    {
        HighScore[] TmpScores = new HighScore[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            TmpScores[i].Name = MyScores[i].Name; // Error Occurs here for `MyScores[i].Name` however in output box both MyScores and TmpScores show null
            TmpScores[i].Score = MyScores[i].Score;
        }
        TmpScores[5].Name = NewName;
        TmpScores[5].Score = NewScore;

        Array.Sort(TmpScores, delegate(HighScore x, HighScore y) { return x.Score.CompareTo(y.Score); });
        Array.Reverse(TmpScores);

        MyScores = new HighScore[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            MyScores[i].Name = TmpScores[i].Name;
            MyScores[i].Score = TmpScores[i].Score;
        }
    }
}

class HighScore
{
    public string Name = "hello world";
    public int Score = 0;
}
```

And here is where I initialise an object of `HighScores`:

```
HighScores GameScores;
protected override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();
    GameScores = new Highscores();
}
```

Surely the objects shouldn't be null if I made them as `new`?

[EDIT]

OK so I've made a new function within the class HighScores to initialise the MyScores objects as new HighScore objects:

```
public void InitScores()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        MyScores[i] = new HighScore();
    }
}
```

Which is called within `protected override void Initialize()` (I'm sure you're all familiar with it, it's standard in XNA). I also have added the same code in the class function: `GameScores.SortHighScores` to initialise `TmpScores`.

Still the same error, still the same place where it occurs, any ideas?

Comment: Do you create instances of `HighScores` for the `MyScores` array somewhere?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to create the instances of `HighScore` for your `MyScores` array. You only create the array in the code above.

So somewhere in the code you need code similar to

```
MyScores[i] = new HighScore();
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work, added `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                GameScores.MyScores[i] = new HighScore();
            }` for both and it still gave me the same error

Comment: Please post the code and the error message. It is difficult to help when we have to guess.

Comment: Thank you, I missed out one little `MyScores[i] = new HighScore` and all is good now I found it :)

Answer (score 1):

The initialization of `GameScores` isn't enough. You don't initialize the values for the internal array of `MyScores` (at least not in the code shown). Of course when you try to use any element of that array you get a `NullReferenceException`

You need to add in the constructor of HighScores a code similar to this

```
public HighScores()
{
    MyScores = new HighScore[5];
    for(x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        MyScores[i] = new HighScore();

}
```

**EDIT:**

This code has the same conceptual error

```
HighScore[] TmpScores = new HighScore[6];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    TmpScores[i].Name = MyScores[i].Name;             
    TmpScores[i].Score = MyScores[i].Score;
}
```

Here you declare an array called TmpScores with space to store 6 elements of type HighScore, but these 6 elements are all `null` and so you can't assign to the variable Name or Score of an element (i) that is null.

Perhaps this code will work for you:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        // Assign to tmpScores an already initialized object HighScore
        TmpScores[i] = MyScores[i];
    }

    TmpScores[5] = new HighScore {Name = NewName, Score = NewScore};
```